# Android: how to play 2 media files simultaneously in sync

Tags: android, audio

I'm trying to play 2 audio files (in this case mp3) simultaneously, so that they start at EXACTLY the same time and play in sync with each other.

My first try was to just use two MediaPlayers, prepare them ahead of time, then call start on each one back to back:

```
    mediaPlayer.start();
    secondPlayer.start();
```

Unfortunately, that only works some of the time.  Sometimes they start together, and then will stay in sync.  Sometimes, there is a very small time gap between when they start, so that they will not be in sync together.

Is there a better technique for playing audio files to ensure that they start simultaneously?  I need to be able to control their volumes independently as well.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try SoundPool,its a better method of dealing with multiple audio files at the same time.

Heres the documentation:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html

Hope this helps

Comment: That partially worked for the short clips that I was using, and played them much more closely to perfectly in sync.  I'm having other problems with that method (looping introduces a very small gap between the end and the next loop), but it did do the trick for getting them to play in sync.  Thanks.

Comment: I also have Same Problem Did you get solution of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35171545/two-object-of-media-player-not-play-song-in-sync-at-same-time) Problem.?