# Two Object of media Player not play song in Sync at same time

Tags: java, android, sockets, media-player

I have working on to one android application.Normal concept of this application is to Play Song in Multiple Device at Same Time.Everything is done but Song is not play in Sync.I have done lot's of R&d to solve this problem but not getting success.but at end I have found one Issue of Android Media Player.For finding this issue I have making one demo Application.Description is follow.

**Demo App Description**

I create a two object of Android media player firstPlayer and secondPlayer.firstPlayer Song playing will be start once App is Lunch.now i have taking one Button in test.xml.once the User will click in this button secondPlayer is start and play same music which I set in firstPlayer.and  I also Seek secondPlayer at Position where firstPlayer is Play.

**Code**

```
  changePlayer = (Button) findViewById(R.id.changePlayer);


    String fileName = "/qq.mp3";
    String baseDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Test App" + fileName;

    Log.e(TAG, "path :" + baseDir);
    try {
        firstPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        secondPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

        firstPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        secondPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

        firstPlayer.setDataSource(baseDir);
        secondPlayer.setDataSource(baseDir);

        firstPlayer.prepare();
        secondPlayer.prepare();

        firstPlayer.start();


    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    changePlayer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (!secondPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Media Player Start M2");
                secondPlayer.start();
            }
            int sek = firstPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
            secondPlayer.seekTo(firstPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
            //firstPlayer.seekTo(sek);

            Log.e(TAG, "Current Playe Time ::" + secondPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
            Log.e(TAG, "First Playe Time ::" + sek);
            Log.e(TAG, "firstPlayer Playe Time ::" + firstPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
            Log.e(TAG, "secondPlayer Playe Time ::" + secondPlayer.getCurrentPosition());

        }
    });
```

**Problem**

- I am getting one Strange problem both media player not play in Sync it's having little bit different for play song.if I seek secondPlayer where firstPlayer is play then it's playing in Sync but it's not happend both player playing different.

**Note**

- I also try to Solve this Issue using any third party Media player but i didn't get luck.I have implement ExoPlayer,VlcPlayer,UniversalPlayer to solve this problem but It's also having same problem.

**Requirement.**

- I want to play song in Sync in Two different object of MediaPlayer.
- Did anyone know about any powerful media player which is not having this delay issue.

I hardly Try to solve this Sync issue but i Didn't get Luck.I want 100% Sync in My Application.Just Like Seedio app in IOS.I also test this in IOS but in IOS it's Working fine Both Player play song with 100% sync.

Please Help me if Anyone have any Idea.

I hope you all are clear with my problem.

**Thank You**

Comment: Did you have a look at this question and answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6231834/3419488

Comment: Thanks for Ans Daan.Is it Possible to Seek using SoundPool ?I think it's also Deprecated.I must need Seek functionality in my App.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? You want to start the second audio player on the current position of the first audio player?

Comment: Yes,I want to play two media player with 100% sync.

Comment: Why is the second sound started when the button is pressed? (I'm trying to understand what you are trying to accomplish to come with a solution.)

Comment: I Want to test both object of android mediaplayer playing with 100% Sync or Not.Because I am making one Group Play Application in this App I must need to play Song in Sync between different devices.So first I test media Player it is working fine or not but I am getting above mention Issue..

Answer (score 0):

The Seek does take some time on a MediaPlayer. (As I understand the official docs: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer)

One idea is to have the second stream not started, seek to a known future position (higher than currect pos of first stream), hope it gets there "in time". And then start the second stream when you get there (time has passed). I have not tested it, just been thinking about it as I want to solve a very similar issue.